# Excel VBA Function Recalculation

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a small Excel VBA Function "MyTableResults"

```
Public Function MyTableResults(Code As String) As Variant
```

Which returns a decimal value from the Database using query filter based on the parameter.

I have used the formula in about 10 cells, runs smoothly.
Function Call e.g.

```
=MyTableResults("Apple")
```

But every time I Insert a Column or Delete a column in the sheet, I m getting a hit to the Function i.e. the function is being called without Actually calling the formula from the sheet and excel is slowing down too much to come back up.

Why does excel call my function when I Edit the Sheet (like insert column, Delete Column) making calculations slower and how can I stop it?
I tried

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

in my function

Comment: For other tip, except my answer, you could add some additional information - which way you call your function? how you set your `Code`, as a string or reference to any cell?

Comment: additionally you could try to use `Activesheet.EnableCalculation = False`. But be careful because it will switch calculation of whole sheet for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add additionally

```
Application.Volatile False
```

at the very beginning, in the first row inside you function, like:

```
Public Function MyTableResults(Code As String) As Variant
    Application.Volatile False

    '...your code here

End Function
```

However, it could help in some situation like inserting rows/columns but will not help when deleting rows (which I've tried).